# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' in django

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I have created nested comment system using django-mptt.(Addding comment,reply to a certain comment,deleting a comment) these functionalities are working fine.But when I am trying to edit particular comment,after editing comment it is not reloading to detail page.In console it showing **"AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split' "**. During this error another error is occuring -> **TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**.Here is my code:

models.py:

```
class Comment(MPTTModel):
    video = models.ForeignKey(Video, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'comments')
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                            null=True,
                            blank=True,
                            related_name='children')
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='replayers')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['created']

    def __str__(self):
        return  f'{self.content[:20]} by {self.user}'
```

views.py:

```
def edit_comment(request, video_id, comment_id):
    video  =  get_object_or_404 (Video, id=video_id)
    comment = Comment.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    print(comment)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        edit_form = CommentUpdateForm(request.POST,instance=comment)
        print(edit_form)
        if  edit_form.is_valid():
            edit_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your comment has been updated!')
            return HttpResponse("")
        else:
            return HttpResponse( "The content of the form is incorrect, please fill in again.")
    else:
        edit_form = CommentUpdateForm(instance=comment)
        print(edit_form)
    context = {
    'edit_form': edit_form,
    'video_id' : video_id,
    'comment_id': comment_id,
    }
    return render(request,'comment/edit_comment.html',context=context)
```

main urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('comment/',include('comment.urls')),
]
```

comment urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from comment import views
app_name = 'comment'

urlpatterns = [
      path('edit-comment/<int:video_id>/<int:comment_id>/', views.edit_comment, name='edit_comment'),
       
]
```

video_details.html:

```
<a href="#" class="button dropdown-item" onclick="edit_load_modal({{ video.id }},{{ comment.id }})">Edit</a>
```

forms.py:

```
class CommentUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(
                        widget=forms.Textarea(
                               attrs={
                               'class': 'form-group form-control',
                               'id':'content',
                               'rows': 3,
                               'cols': 10,
                               }
                        )
                      )
    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['content',]
```

edit_comment.html:

```
<form action="{% url 'comment:edit_comment' video_id comment_id %}" method="POST" id="edit_comment_form">
        <div class="form-group" >
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ edit_form.content }}
        </div>
        <button type="submit" onclick = "confirm_submit({{ video_id }}, {{ comment_id }})"  class = "btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    </form>



<script>
   function  confirm_submit(video_id, comment_id ){

        // call ajax to exchange data with the backend
        $.ajax ({
            url :  '/comment/edit-comment/' + video_id + '/' + comment_id + '/',
            type :  'POST' ,
            data : { content: $('#content').val(), },
            // success callback
            success: function ( e ){
                if (e  ===  ''){
                    parent.location.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    }
    </script>
```

Error details:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 53885)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 279, in write

    self._write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "E:\Bohubrihi\Django\VE\Bohubrihi\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 116, in handle_error

    super().handle_error()
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 650, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socketserver.py", line 720, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "E:\Bohubrihi\Django\VE\Bohubrihi\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 171, in handle

    self.handle_one_request()
  File "E:\Bohubrihi\Django\VE\Bohubrihi\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 194, in handle_one_request
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "E:\Bohubrihi\Django\VE\Bohubrihi\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 111, in close
    super().close()
  File "C:\Users\Sudipto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

How can I solve this problem?Any Suggetion?

Comment: Please add complete error traceback to the question

Comment: Sorry.I have updated now error traceback.

Comment: Do you find solution ?

Comment: Any updates here? facing the same issue with Django 4.1 while working with AWS SES